# Parallel for each nested in for loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++-amp

I have about 4000 vectors having 3000 dimensions and I need to calculate difference vector pair wise.

Here come the questions.
I tried this in two ways.

```
differ = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * testNum * trainNum * featureDim);
array_view<double, 2> differAMP(testNum, trainNum, featureDim, differ);
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tc);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
parallel_for_each(
        differAMP.extent,
        [=](concurrency::index<3> idx) restrict(amp) {
        differAMP[idx] = (test(idx[0], idx[2]) - train(idx[1], idx[2]));
}
);
```

But vs throws a runtime exception because the memory limitation, I think.
Then I changed the code

```
differ = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) trainNum * featureDim);
array_view<double, 2> differAMP(trainNum, featureDim, differ);
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tc);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
parallel_for_each(
        differAMP.extent,
        [=](concurrency::index<2> idx) restrict(amp) {
        differAMP[idx] = (test(testIndex, idx[1]) - train(idx[0], idx[1]));
}
);
```

I run this for each test case inside a loop.
However, vs threw an array_view removed exception.
Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: call `differAMP.synchronize()`?

Comment: where? After the second code?

Comment: I need more context to answer this question. Where/when does the exception occur? Where is the code that accesses `differAMP` after the parallel_for_each has completed?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you fail because you run out of memory. In the second case you probably fails because your task exceeds the 2 second TDR limit. Remember that a `parallel_for_each` queues the work to the GPU's DMA buffer asynchronously. So placing this in a `for` loop will cause all of the

```
for (int testIndex = 0; testIndex < testNum; ++testIndex)
{
    differ = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) trainNum * featureDim);
    array_view<double, 2> differAMP(trainNum, featureDim, differ);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tc);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
    parallel_for_each(
        differAMP.extent,
        [=](concurrency::index<2> idx) restrict(amp) {
        differAMP[idx] = (test(testIndex, idx[1]) - train(idx[0], idx[1]));
    });

    // Force this parallel_for_each to finish before running the next one.
    differAmp.source_accelerator_view.wait();
}
```

The code above prevents all the work being queued and executed in one block causing a TDR timeout which will throw an exception.

You can also alter the queuing behavior by creating a view with a specific queuing mode. Immediate mode forces tasks to be queued immediately, improving latency at the expense of throughput.

```
accelerator acc(accelerator::default_accelerator);
acc.create_view(queuing_mode::queuing_mode_immediate);
```